# What is the probability that the last card is king if we are dealt $13$ cards from a well-shuffled desk?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A  player  is  randomly  dealt  13  cards  from  a  standard, well-shuffled 52-card  deck. 
>   What  is  the  probability  the  13th  card  dealt  is  a  king?

Comment: Do you know the probability that the _first_ card is a king?

Comment: How about if you immediately took the 13th card - can you see that it is equally likely to be any card from the pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hint

The 13th card you drew might as well have been the *only* card you drew. The other cards didn't even factor into it. Do you see why?

Now what is the probability that if you draw 1 card from the deck, it is a king?

Comment: I think I don't understand your argument.

Comment: @ndakostan Can you pinpoint where you are stuck? Which part do you not follow? It was a hint, not a complete argument.

Comment: I am stuck in your saying that "The 13th card you drew might as well have been the only card you drew. The other cards didn't even factor into it". Can you explain more? Thank you very much.

Comment: @ndakostan Sure. As I am dealt the 13 cards, I could just set aside the first 12 face down, and then only look at the 13th card and not look at the first 13, and that would be equivalent. And the 13th card is random from the deck just like the 1st card is random from the deck.

Comment: I see it. But do you mean "not look at the first 12" or " not look at the first 13".

Comment: @ndakostan Good catch! I'm sorry, I meant, "not look at the first 12".

Comment: Thank you very much. Very easy to understand with your explain.